# Is there a way to make a button-click trigger opposite actions depending on the value of a variable at a given time?

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement, button, click

I'm kind of new to jQuery and therefore not really used to it, so I apologize if my question is a stupid one.
I want to have some sort of menu pop-out of the left side of the screen by clicking a button (which is quite easy because I managed to do that) but I also want to be able to make that same menu go back to where it came from when I click the same button.

I think it's the same principle as a collapsible section and I found easy ways to implement one using Bootstrap but I couldn't make it exactly like I wanted it so I figured I'll make it myself using jQuery.

In my code the first click works and the menu pops out, but the second click is supposed to make it go away but doesn't work for some reason. `modalWindow` is the the menu that's supposed to pop out and `hamburger` being the button.

What is it that I am missing?

```js
var modalRight = $('.modalwindow').css('right');
$('.hamburger').click(function() {
  if (modalRight === '900px') {
    $('.modalwindow').animate({
      'right': '300px'
    }, 200);
    $('.image').css('opacity', '50%')
  } else {
    $('.modalwindow').animate({
      'right': '900px'
    }, 200);
    $('.image').css('opacity', '100%')
  };
```

```
<div class="container modalwindow"> 
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
                <h5>SHOP</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>HOME</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>GUITARS</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>BASSES</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>ACOUSTICS</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>AMPS</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>EFFECTS PEDALS</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>AUDIO</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>PARTS</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>ACCESSORIES</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>LIFESTYLE</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="justify-content: space-between">
                <h5>SQUIER</h5>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img style="height:20%;width:20%;" src="next.svg"/></a></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

```
.modalwindow
{
    position:relative;
    bottom:2246px;
    width:650px;
    right:900px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height:380px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: This is absolutely possible, but to debug your problem we would ideally need to see your HTML and CSS too. Note that a much easier approach is to have CSS position the element and animate it. Then you can just toggle that class on and off.

Comment: Sure ! I'll send you the HTML and CSS right away.
I didn't really get your suggestion about having the CSS position and animate the element, could you be a little more specific please ? thanks for your reply.